# Method to retrieve resources from context.xml in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, context.xml

I wanted to retrieve values from my context.xml, and I've found this snippet of code to do so:

```
  // Acquire an instance of our specified bean class
  MyBean bean = new MyBean();

  // Customize the bean properties from our attributes
  Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
  Enumeration addrs = ref.getAll();
  while (addrs.hasMoreElements()) {
      RefAddr addr = (RefAddr) addrs.nextElement();
      String name = addr.getType();
      String value = (String) addr.getContent();
      if (name.equals("foo")) {
          bean.setFoo(value);
      } else if (name.equals("bar")) {
          try {
              bean.setBar(Integer.parseInt(value));
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              throw new NamingException("Invalid 'bar' value " + value);
          }
      }
  }

  // Return the customized instance
  return (bean);
```

I wanted to know if there was a method to do the exact same thing but with less steps

Comment: 1. The exact version of Tomcat you are trying to run this on (x.y.z.) =?

Comment: 2. What component runs the code? (A listener, a valve that have access to Tomcat internals? A web application?)

Comment: 3. "// Acquire an instance of our specified bean class". The comment is lying. It does not look at what is specified in configuration. It does not "acquire" an instance. It creates its own one.

Comment: a web application on Tomcat 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a web application on Tomcat 8.0

1. Tomcat 8.0 has reached End of Life. Do not use it. See "Migration Guide" at tomcat.apache.org to upgrade to Tomcat 8.5 or 9.0.
2. See "[JDNI Resources](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)" in Tomcat documentation. E.g. `factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"` can be used to create an arbitrary bean.
3. If you just need a set of configurable properties, defining them with "Parameter" element in [Context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters) will be easier. A web application will get those values via `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getInitParameter(name)` API.